# PyQt: QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory using a default directory, user independant

Tags: python, pyqt

When using the `QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory` I've found the way to specify the default path to a directory. I wanted to use a default directory somewhere in my (user) home folder on my Linux (Mint) machine. I used:

```
my_dir = QtGui.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(
    self,
    "Open a folder",
    "/home/my_user_name/",
    QtGui.QFileDialog.ShowDirsOnly
    )
```

Which worked beautifully. The next 'level' is now to be able to do this for every user. I tried the standard Linux way and change `/home/my_user_name/` to `~/`. That did not work. It resulted in the working directory instead of the user's dir.

Should I use more system arguments when calling my app from the terminal? Or am I missing a PyQt function?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can get the user's home directory by using [os.path.expanduser](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser)

```
>>> from os.path import expanduser
>>> expanduser("~")
/home/user_name
```

This works on Windows and Linux.

Your code block will look like this then

```
my_dir = QtGui.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(
    self,
    "Open a folder",
    expanduser("~"),
    QtGui.QFileDialog.ShowDirsOnly
)
```

Comment: Simply forgot to use the os module. Maybe a broader tip for myself. Combine more modules (my projects so far have not been very big).

Answer (score 3):

You can also get home folder for any user by obtaining the environment variable "HOME" through `os.getenv(varname)`.

```
>>> import os
>>> os.getenv("HOME")
'/home/my_user_name'
```

Your code could look like this:

```
import os
home = os.getenv("HOME")

my_dir = QtGui.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(
    self,
    "Open a folder",
    home,
    QtGui.QFileDialog.ShowDirsOnly
    )
```